# In IBM Websphere commerce while showing recently viewed product on store front, it is showing one product multiple times on product display page

Tags: wcs

In IBM Websphere commerce while showing recently viewed product on store front, it is showing one product multiple times instead of different product on product display page, how to resolve it.

Comment: Which version, feature pack, fix pack are you on? Does the product appear twice in the solr response?  or is it while displaying in  the page?

Comment: It is solved.
Actually it is wcs 7 i am working on, and the data is iterating completely correct in JSON format, but while iterating in java code it is taking a particular id and displaying it multiple times.